# All selected DataGridview Rows to display to a textbox of another form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm try to display all selected rows of my DataGridView to one textbox only with multiple lines. However, all codes I've tried isn't working.

Here is a sample of what I tried after I selected all rows of my DataGridView

```
Dim form2 As New Form2
Form2.txtreceipt.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.ToString
Form2.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectedRows returns a collection of DataGridViewRow, not a specific cell of a single given DataGridViewRow. Presumably, your DataGridView is bound to a BindingSource, if that is the case then you can pass the BindingSource to Form2 as a parameter in the New constructor and set up the control(s) data bindings there.

So for example, your Form2 would contain the following code:

```
Sub New(ByVal source As BindingSource)
    txtreceipt.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", source, "Receipt", True))
End Sub
```

And then whenever you wanted to display the form you'd call:

```
Using frm2 As Form2 = New Form2(BindingSource1)
    frm.ShowDialog()
End Using
```